# What is the correct way to describe an instance of a multi-parameter class in Haskell?

Tags: haskell

An instance of a single parameter type class (SPTC) is described in the [Haskell Language Report 2010](https://www.haskell.org/onlinereport/haskell2010/haskellch4.html#x10-750004.3) as: "*an instance declaration declares that **a type** is an instance of a class*". The [Haskell Wiki](https://wiki.haskell.org/Multi-parameter_type_class) says if we think of a SPTC as a set of types, then a multi-parameter type class (MPTC) is a relation between types. **Listing 1** contains an example of a SPTC and a MPTC.

I am looking for a simple English description of MPTC. My attempt at a definition is:

An instance of a MPTC is an instance for an n-tuple of types, n>=2, that satisfy the functional dependencies stated in the class definition. Where a functional dependency describes the properties of the relations between the n-tuple of types. The relations must be functions i.e. in x -> y every x value should be associated with only one y value.

Is there a better more natural description?

**Listing 1**

```
{-# LANGUAGE MultiParamTypeClasses  #-}
{-# LANGUAGE   FunctionalDependencies  #-}

class Add1 a  where           
 plus1    :: a -> a -> a     
  

instance Add1 Integer where     
  plus1 x  y       =   x + y
  
t0 =  plus1 (2::Integer)  (2::Integer)


class Add2 a b c | a b -> c where
  plus2 :: a -> b -> c

instance Add2 Integer Integer Integer where
    plus2 x y = x + y

-- The following instance works because a and b of Add2 are uniquely instantiated
instance Add2 Integer Double Double where
    plus2 x y = fromIntegral x + y

t1 =  plus2 (2::Integer)  (2::Integer)
t2 =  plus2 (2::Integer)  (2.0::Double)
```

Comment: Functional dependencies are an optional part of a MPTC, and they require a separate language extension. A type class is a (multi-argument) relation between types. A functional dependency like `a b -> c` just asserts that the relation is not just any relation, but, in fact, a function. (A function is a special kind of a relation).

Comment: I have added the fact about functions. But my attempt at a simple definition is getting a bit long.

Comment: A relation (functional or not) is a set of tuples, and an instance of a type class (multiparametric or not, with or without functional dependencies) is a single element of the set. Well that's before you consider the methods...

Comment: Is it fair to say: An instance of a type class with an n-tuple type variables, where n>=1, is defined for an n-tuple of types.

Comment: I guess you could say it this way.

Answer (score 2):

Mathematically, a relation is just a set of tuples. So an MPTC is a set of tuples of types.

A function `A->C` is a relation with the specific property that for each `a::A`, there is exactly one tuple in the set that has `a` as its first element. A fundep on an MPTC only requires that there is *at most* one such tuple, which is enough so that given the knowledge that there is an instance with `a`, you can find the unique `c::C` belonging to it.

If the fundep is `A B -> C`, it means that for each sub-tuple `(a::A, b::B)` there exist at most `(a,b,c)` in the class, so again you can extract this unique `c`.

Comment: I have added an explicit mention of a relation.

Comment: A class “is” not an instance, no. A class _has_ instances.

Comment: Thanks. If we say an instance of an SPTC has a instance for a type, can we say a MPTC has an instance for a tuple of types?

Comment: It's not particularly common, but yeah, I'd say it makes sense.